# wire framing program for mockup

Tags: wireframe

I am starting a new app development and the other two programmers are located in different area so we have decided to us wire framing for initial design work.  Does anyone have any suggestion of a good wire frame program, willing to paid but free sound great as well…

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio has Wireframe capability under the Software and Database template area.  It is useable, but if you don't already own it or have access, it is not the best.

Pencil is a Free/open source wireframe tool and is available for Windows/Linux/Mac and is still being actively developed (as of November 2012)

If money is no object, I would recommend Protoshare (http://www.protoshare.com) with the caveat that it can, at times, be slow due to it's implementation (javascript).

You can also see many different tools available on Mashable: http://mashable.com/2010/07/15/wireframing-tools/
Most of these offer a free trial period of ~30 days and then start at $9 per month for the subscription versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for [Pidoco](http://pidoco.com).

It's a german company based in Berlin and we develop a online prototyping tool.

We have nice features like:

- Interactive prototypes
- Collaboration and invitations
- iOS App to simulate mobile prototypes (Android is coming soon)

You can start with a 30 days free trial and then plans are starting at 9$ per month.

Answer (score 0):

The wire-framing tool that I work with is called Axure.Its very useful in the way that your prototype can be generated and uploaded online so it can be seen from any computer with just one link.

The website for Axure also offers many tutorials if you are a beginner with the tools. The different tutorials are specific to website design, or mobile app design.

I highly recommend it.